# Find the value of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots}} }$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

How to prove that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\dots}} }=2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}=a$. Then squaring both sides we have $a^2=2+a$. This is a quadratic equation in $a$. Find the solutions of $a$. Then $a=2 $ or $a=-1$. Since $a>0, a=2$.

Comment: The second solution to the equation $a^2=2+a$ is not $-2$ but $-1$.

Comment: You also have to show it converges.

Comment: Exactly as @martycohen said: You've proved that *if* it has a solution, then 2 is the solution; but you need to prove the antecedent: how do you know it has a solution?

Comment: Hint: if $\sqrt{2} < x < 2$, show that $\sqrt{2} < \sqrt{2+x} < 2$ and that $2-\sqrt{2+x} < 2-x$.